# About Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. I know that $P$ consists of all $p$-elements in $N_{G}(P)$. My question is the following:

If $P$ is any $p$-subgroup of $G$, and if there is no $p$-element of $G-P$ normalizes $P$ in $G$, then is it true that $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$? If it is not, maybe someone knows a counter example. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, assuming I read correctly (it is a bit unclearly stated). If $P$ is a $p$-subgroup such that $P$ is the set of $p$-elements of $N_G(P)$ then $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P$ is a $p$-subgroup, but not Sylow, then it is contained in a Sylow one $P_1$. Then there is a subgroup $P_2<P_1$ such that $[P_2:P]=p$ and $P$ is normal in $P_2$.